# Source of Node<Object> in the Visual Studio memory snapshot

Tags: visual-studio

I am doing memory profiling for my application using Visual Studio diagnostic tool. I find that there is Node takes up a lot of memory (based on Inclusive Size Diff. (bytes).  (see below #1). And when I click on the first instance of Node, 'Referenced Objects', I see Node is referencing other Node. And I see something like 'Overlapped data' in the attribute.

How can I find out where is creating these Node as they are from mscorlib.ni.dll.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weapon of choice when you are rooting through these .NET Framework objects is a good decompiler.  I use Reflector, there are others.

You see an opaque `Node<T>` object back.  Just type it into the Search box, out pops but a few types that use it.  Most are in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace.  Well, look no further, the profiler already told you about that one.  Clearly it is the `Stack<T>` class in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace that's storing *Nodes*.

Your profiler told you there is just **one** Stack<> class object that owns these objects.  Well good, that narrows it down to just a *single* object.  It just happens to have 208 elements.  Hmm, well, not that much, is it?

---

That's not where you have to stop, the Stack<> class is a pretty useless class, nobody ever actually uses it in their code.  Keep using the decompiler and let it search for usages of that class.

Ah, nice, that's a very short list as well.  You see System.Data.ProviderBase show up several times, hmm, this question probably isn't related to querying dbases.  Only other set of references is `System.PinnableBufferCache`.

"Pinnable buffers", whoa, that's a match.  Pinning a buffer is important when you ask native code to get a job done to fill a managed array.  With `BeginRead()`, the universal asynchronous I/O call.  The driver needs a stable reference to the array while it is working on the async I/O request.  Getting a stable buffer requires pinning in .NET. And big bingo in the profiler data, you see `OverlappedData`, the [core data-structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows to do async I/O.

---

Long story short, you found [this guy's project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927243/gc-behavior-when-pinning-an-object).  Programmers noticed, not very often.

---

Knowing when the **stop** profiling is very important.  You cannot change code written by another programmer.  And nobody at Microsoft thinks that guy did anything wrong.  He didn't, caches are Good Things.

You are most definitely **done**.  Congratulations.