# What happens when the memory used by pinned objects in .NET exceeds the size of the ephemeral segment?

Tags: .net, memory, garbage-collection

From the question found here:
[GC behavior when pinning an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927243/gc-behavior-when-pinning-an-object)

It would appear that pinning an object in memory (via the fixed keyword? I am not terribly familiar with the usage of object pinning and I do not know if there are multiple methods to do so in the sense described by the linked question) prevents its promotion across garbage collection generations, so what happens if the total consumed memory of pinned objects actually exceeds the ephemeral segment size?

I'm mainly asking out of academic curiosity. I could not locate any information regarding this scenario in my searching and while I could certainly test this out personally, I wanted to check if anyone already knew before I dive into what could be a somewhat time consuming experiment/investigation.

Edit: Upon some re-reading, I suspect the behavior of the GC may be to always shift which segment is considered which generation around the objects, with the only thing being prevented by pinning in the compacting step. Unfortunately, the documentation I could locate such as here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals was still somewhat unclear on this point.

Assuming that the GC always performs a shuffling of which section of memory is considered a generation and the only movement of objects is the compaction step, pinned objects would always end up in gen 2 before you could exceed the ephemeral segment. In that case, my question, as per the comment, is entirely invalid.

Comment: The posted answer demonstrated that pinning does *not* prevent an object from being promoted.  So the premise of this question is not valid.  There is a lot less magic behind "promotion" than most .NET programmers tend to assume.  It is easy to mentally model it as an involved copy from one section of the heap to another.  Not what happens at all, it just changes a single "this is the gen#0 heap segment" pointer.  Or gen#1.  Getting an entire ephemeral segment pinned is otherwise excessively hard to do, the large object heap helps a lot.  The GC does not suck.

Comment: @HansPassant To clarify, I was wondering if the GC displayed the same 'clever' behavior of re-assigning which section of memory was a given generation or if it only looked for the narrow circumstance of when there was fragmentation.